# Error while Building Android Application Project

Tags: android, eclipse, build-error

I am having this strange problem while trying to create a new Android application project. Whenever I create a new Android application Project I get a Red Exclamation mark on it. I am also getting some Errors in the console about which I have no idea.

```
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject] Versions found are:
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject] Path: C:\Users\Umair Ahmed\workspace\ExampleProject\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject]  Length: 1184670
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject]  SHA-1: fde22d8d2ef6363324a3d79a1dd16c8645c25564
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject] Path: C:\Users\Umair Ahmed\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject]  Length: 1184450
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject]  SHA-1: e19387dc3b060af32f5401f84fbe246635256955
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2015-07-20 07:45:09 - ExampleProject] C:\Users\Umair
```

In the past I used to fix it by deleting the Android dependencies folder which has a red cross on it. But now it is not working because then I get a red cross in the main src folder and that old (R cannot be resolved to a variable) error will appear. 
   Being a beginner in Android I have no idea what to do with this thing. It just happens one day and goes after 1-2 weeks on its own. Any help will be appreciated. Nothing so far from other answers has worked and what used to work is now not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you are *still* using Eclipse, the new **AppCompat v7 come along with Android Support v4**.

**Remove** your own `ExampleProject\libs\android-support-v4.jar`, **clean** the project and **build**.

Comment: Deleted and cleaned the project but nothing changed!

Comment: The Console is now showing errors like.
[2015-07-20 08:07:12 - ExampleProject] C:\Users\Umair Ahmed\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2015-07-20 08:07:12 - ExampleProject] 
[2015-07-20 08:07:12 - ExampleProject] C:\Users\Umair Ahmed\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.

Comment: I guess AppCompat v7 is not well included in Eclipse, you are missing some res files, try to copy it from `android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/`

Comment: Tried this as well. 
There is also a cross in Libraries tab under Build path on "Android Dependencies" folder. Inside the cross is on appcompat_v7. It says "C:\Users\Umair Ahmed\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin (missing)"